# How to set up Laravel 5.2 to connect to API

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a backend C++ application that receives JSON requests using a standard TCP connection. This application manages all the business logic (user authentication, transaction processing, data requests and validation).

How do I need to setup Laravel 5.2 to connect to this server for user authentication and also transaction processing? I do not need any database on the Laravel side as all the data will be accessed through the C++ application.

As a bonus, I would also like to incorporate JWT for the user authentication part if that will be possible.

The code below is the way I currently connect to the application server using standard PHP. I want the same functionality but in a more Laravel way.

```
class tcp_client
{
    private $sock;

    function __construct()
    {
        // create the socket
        $this->sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
        if (!is_resource($this->sock))
        {
            // throw exception
        }

        // set socket options
        $this->set_options();
    }

    function connect($host, $port)
    {
        $timeout = 3;
        $startTime = time();
        while (!socket_connect($this->sock, $host, $port))
        {
            if ((time() - $startTime ) >= $timeout)
            {
                // throw exception
            }
            sleep(1);
        }
    }

    private function set_options()
    {
        if (!socket_set_option($this->sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array('sec' => 5,
                    'usec' => 0)))
        {
            // throw exception
        }

        if (!socket_set_option($this->sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, array('sec' => 5,
                    'usec' => 0)))
        {
            // throw exception
        }
    }

    public function request($request)
    {
        // the first 6 characters will indicate the length of the JSON string
        $request = str_pad(strlen($request), 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . $request;

        //Send the message to the server
        if (!socket_send($this->sock, $request, strlen($request), 0))
        {
            // throw exception
        }

        //Now receive header from server
        $header = 0;
        if (socket_recv($this->sock, $header, 6, MSG_WAITALL) === FALSE)
        {
            // throw exception
        }  

        //Now receive body from server
        $body = "";
        if (socket_recv($this->sock, $body, $header, MSG_WAITALL) === FALSE)
        {
            // throw exception
        }

        return $body;
    }

}
```

Comment: Found other people struggling with similar situation [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/3b4lu2/correct_structure_for_consuming_rest_api_with/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to sort this out on my own by mimicking the DatabaseUserProvider.

1. Create folder `App\Blah` with sub folders `App\Blah\Auth` and `App\Blah\TCP`
2. Create a new user provider

   ```
   > php artisan make:provider App\Blah\Auth\BlahUserProvider
   ```
3. Copied the contents of `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\DatabaseUserProvider.php` to the new provider (`BlahUserProvider.php`) and changed the class name back to `BlahUserProvider`.
4. Created `App\Blah\TCP\TCPClient.php` and copied the contents of the class in my question to this file.
5. Change the namespace and use the `TCPClient` and `stdClass` in `BlahUserProvider.php`

   ```
   namespace App\Blah\Auth;
   use App\Blah\TCP\TCPClient;
   use stdClass;
   ```
6. Replaced the contents of function `retrieveByCredentials` in `BlahUserProvider` with

   ```
   public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
   { 
     $tcp_request = "{\"request\":\"login\","
                  . "\"email\":\"" . $credentials['email'] . "\","
                  . "\"password\":\"" . $credentials['password'] . "\"}";

     $tcp_result = json_decode(str_replace("\n","\\n",$this->conn->request($tcp_request)), true);

     $user = new stdClass();
     $user->id = $tcp_result['user']['id'];
     $user->name = $tcp_result['user']['name'];

     return $this->getGenericUser($user);
   }
   ```
7. I also replaced function `retrieveById` with the same contents as function `retrieveByCredentials` for now just so the user can log in because I still have to create the request in the C++ application.
8. Extended the `createUserProvider` function in `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\CreatesUserProviders.php` to include my new driver and also added function `createBlahProvider`

   ```
   public function createUserProvider($provider)
   {
     $config = $this->app['config']['auth.providers.' . $provider];

     if (isset($this->customProviderCreators[$config['driver']]))
     {
       return call_user_func(
               $this->customProviderCreators[$config['driver']], $this->app, $config
       );
     }

     switch ($config['driver'])
     {
       case 'database':
           return $this->createDatabaseProvider($config);
       case 'eloquent':
           return $this->createEloquentProvider($config);
       case 'blah':
           return $this->createBlahProvider($config);
       default:
           throw new InvalidArgumentException("Authentication user provider [{$config['driver']}] is not defined.");
     }
   }

   protected function createBlahProvider($config)
   {
     $connection = new \App\Blah\TCP\TCPClient();
     return new \App\Blah\Auth\BlahUserProvider($connection, $this->app['hash'], $config['model']);
   }
   ```
9. Changed the provider in `config\auth.php` to the blah user provider

   ```
   'providers' => [
     'users' => [
       'driver' => 'blah',
       'model' => App\User::class,
   ],
   ```

Comment: This is very helful. Thanks for taking time to write it.